# Replace values in named vector with values from another named vector

Tags: r

I have two vectors, say :

```
x <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)
names(x) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
y <- c(33,44,55)
names(y) <- c("b", "d", "f")
```

so that `x` is

```
a  b  c  d  e  f 
2  3  5  7  9 11
```

and `y` is

```
 b  d  f 
33 44 55
```

I want to replace the values in `x` with values in `y` that have the same name so that the result would be for the new `x`:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f 
2 33  5 44  9 55
```

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I can't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the names of `y` as a subset on `x`, then replace with `y`.

```
x[names(y)] <- y
x
# a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 2 33  5 44  9 55
```

Another option is `replace()`, which basically does the same as above but returns the result and does not change `x`.

```
replace(x, names(y), y)
# a  b  c  d  e  f 
# 2 33  5 44  9 55
```