# Replacement of column values based on a named vector

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider the following named vector `vec` and tibble `df`:

```
vec <- c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "c")
df <- tibble(col = rep(1:3, c(4, 2, 5)))

df
# # A tibble: 11 x 1
#      col
#    <int>
#  1     1
#  2     1
#  3     1
#  4     1
#  5     2
#  6     2
#  7     3
#  8     3
#  9     3
# 10     3
# 11     3
```

I would like to replace the values in the `col` column with the corresponding named values in `vec`.

I'm looking for a `tidyverse` approach, that doesn't involve converting `vec` as a tibble.

I tried the following, without success:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(col = map(
    vec,
    ~ str_replace(col, names(.x), .x)
  ))
```

Expected output:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 1
   col    
   <chr>
 1 a    
 2 a    
 3 a    
 4 a    
 5 b    
 6 b    
 7 c    
 8 c    
 9 c    
10 c    
11 c
```

Comment: `df %>%
 mutate(col = str_replace_all(col, vec))` should do the job.

Comment: @tmfmnk please add as an answer.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270500/replace-values-in-named-vector-with-values-from-another-named-vector-in-r

Comment: A more flexible version of @tmfmnk solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76433751/use-named-vector-to-create-column-in-pipe-chain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `col` :

```
df$col1 <- vec[as.character(df$col)]
```

Or in `mutate` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(col1 = vec[as.character(col)])
#   col col1 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     1 a    
# 3     1 a    
# 4     1 a    
# 5     2 b    
# 6     2 b    
# 7     3 c    
# 8     3 c    
# 9     3 c    
#10     3 c    
#11     3 c
```

Comment: I'm looking for a tidyverse-compatible approach that I can use in a pipe chain.

Comment: Added an option to use this in pipes. @Junitar

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, col1 := vec[as.character(col)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `Base R` solution is:

```
df$col <- vec[match(df$col,as.numeric(names(vec)))]
```