# use named vector to create column in pipe chain

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

In a pipe chain, I want to use a named vector to create a new column which matches the names of the vector with the string of a column:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(my_label = c("car", "house", "Bike", "ca"),
                 xx = c(1, 2, 3, 5))
#   my_label xx
# 1      car  1
# 2    house  2
# 3     Bike  3
# 4       ca  5

named_vars <- c(
  "car" = "Nice car",
  "ca" = "Cat",
  "house" = "Large house")
#           car            ca         house 
#    "Nice car"         "Cat" "Large house"
```

The following code works if the named vector contains all the strings within the column, which it doesn't in this case so it returns an `NA` (if it is missing I want to keep the original (`Bike` in this example):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = named_vars[my_label])
#   my_label xx        new
# 1      car  1    Nice car
# 2    house  2 Large house
# 3     Bike  3        <NA>
# 4       ca  5         Cat
```

As a workaround, this produces the output I want:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new = ifelse(my_label %in% names(named_vars), named_vars[my_label], my_label))
#   my_label xx         new
# 1      car  1    Nice car
# 2    house  2 Large house
# 3     Bike  3        Bike
# 4       ca  5         Cat
```

**I am wondering is there a shorter way to write this?**

I tried `stringr::str_replace_all` but it combines `ca` and `car` to give incorrect output (`Nice Catr` instead of `Nice car`):

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(new = str_replace_all(my_label, named_vars))
#   my_label xx         new
# 1      car  1   Nice Catr
# 2    house  2 Large house
# 3     Bike  3        Bike
# 4       ca  5         Cat
```

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(new = coalesce(named_vars[my_label], my_label))
#   my_label xx         new
# 1      car  1    Nice car
# 2    house  2 Large house
# 3     Bike  3        Bike
# 4       ca  5         Cat
```

These two statements are functionality equivalent here:

```r
coalesce(named_vars[my_label], my_label)
if_else(is.na(named_vars[my_label]), my_label, named_vars[my_label])
```